# How to replace string.empty to "0"

Tags: c#

Just like the title says.

I've tried doing `str.Replace("","0");` but it gave me error because `oldValue` has zero length.

Is it possible to replace `string.Empty` into something?

Edit:

I am maintaining a program and I encountered that the program was calling a method that'll return a string then be converted to Int32.

int x = Convert.toInt32(Method1());

```
public string Method1()
{
      string retString = string.Empty;
      //Do Something
      return retString
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Every string contains an infinite number of empty strings... could you give sample input and output? If str if "xy" for example, what do you want the result to be?

Comment: Are you just looking for something like `if (str == "") str = "0";`? If so, that's not at all what `string.Replace` is for. If not, please update your question.

Comment: Jack, are you aware you don't need to write your own method to convert a string to an int32? there already is `int.Parse`, `int.TryParse`, and as you mention `Convert.ToInt32`

Comment: @Sayse - Hi there. I encountered an error on Convert.ToInt32() that's why I thought I need to replace the string.empty to a zero before the return...

Comment: @JackFrost - I've created an answer showing how to use `int.TryParse` it should suit your requirements better

Comment: @JackFrost: You're trying to fix a symptom instead of the actual issue. If the calling code converts/parses the string into an integer anyway, then the method should return an integer to begin with. As it is now, the method is lying about its intention and post condition. For starters you might want to pull the conversion from the calling code into the method.

Answer (score 2):

String.Replace takes two string arguments oldValue and newValue. You specified the newValue 0 however an empty string is not legal for the oldValue.

try below code :-

```
str.Replace(" ","0");
```

or you can just assign "0" to emptry string as below :-

```
if(str == string.Empty)
{
   str = "0";
}
```

or making it simple :-

```
String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str) ? "0" : str;
```

Comment: That won't throw an exception, but it also won't do what the OP wants.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply return `"0"` for null, zero length or whitespace string using this one-liner:

```
return String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str) ? "0" : str;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't *replace* *empty string* within the string, but you can replace, say, *spaces*, e.g.

```
  str = str.Replace(" ", "0"); // providing str is not null
```

Or you can *substitute* empty string with `"0"`:

```
  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
    str = "0";
```

When *parsing* `string` into `int` you can do something like that:

```
  int x = String.IsNullOrEmpty(str) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

In method() you can do:

```
return String.IsNullOrEmpty(retString) ? "0" : retString;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if the value is empty and then set the value to zero, otherwise use the default value you can use an inline if like so:

```
return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(retString ) ? "0" : retString;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that str is empty then you may use star="a"
If you want to check then write statement in if condition.

Answer (score 0):

After your edit:

To convert an empty string to `0`, and parse a non-empty string as an integer, I wouldn't deal with a `"0"` at all, but combine the two in a single method. For example:

```
int Parse(string s, int d = 0) {
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
    return d;

  return int.Parse(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

```
public string Method1()
{
      string retString = string.Empty;
      //Do Something
      return string.IsNullOrEmpty(retString)?"0":retString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to replace string.Empty by "0". It will throw ArgumentException.

```
    An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll.
Additional information: String cannot be of zero length.
```

You can try following code:

```
if(retString == string.Empty)
{
retString = "0";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your best option would be `int.TryParse`, if you encounter a string that can't be set to a valid value, it will set it to the default value for an integer (0) as well as returning a boolean so you can know this has happened.

```
int myInt;
if(!int.TryParse(myStringVariable, out myInt))
{
    //Invalid integer you can put something here if you like but not needed
    //myInt has been set to zero
}
```

```
//The same code without the if statement, still sets myInt
int.TryParse(myStringVariable, out myInt);
```

Answer (score 0):

By using separate method like:

```
private String ZeroIf(String str)
{
   return String.IsNullOrEmpty(str)? "0": str;
}
```